# Show that $\int_{0}^{\pi\over4 }{\ln\left({1\over 2}e^2\sec^2(x)\right)\ln(2\sin^2(x))}{\mathrm dx\over \cos^2(x)}=-\pi\ln{2}?$

Tags: integration

I am just curious how is this complicated integral gives a simple closd form

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi\over4 }{\ln\left({1\over 2}e^2\sec^2(x)\right)\ln(2\sin^2(x))}{\mathrm dx\over \cos^2(x)}=-\pi\ln{2}\tag1$$

$u=\cos^2(x)$ then $\mathrm du=-2\cos(x)\sin(x)\mathrm dx$

$\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)=1-u$

$\cos(x)\sin(x)=\sqrt{u(1-u)}$

$${1\over 2}\int_{1/2}^{1}\ln\left({e^2\over 2u}\right)\ln(2-2u){\mathrm du\over u\sqrt{u(1-u)}}\tag2$$

$\ln\left({e^2\over 2u}\right)\ln(2-2u)=2\ln(2-2u)-\ln(2u)\ln(2-2u)$

$$\int_{1/2}^{1}\ln(2-2u){\mathrm du\over u\sqrt{u(1-u)}}-\int_{1/2}^{1}\ln(2u)\ln(2-2u){\mathrm du\over u\sqrt{u(1-u)}}\tag3$$

**How do we prove $(1)?$**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following results are elementary:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log(t)\,dt = -1,\qquad \int_{0}^{1}\log(1+t^2)\,dt\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}-2+\tfrac{\pi}{2}+\log 2 \tag{A}$$
the following results a bit less, but they still follow from integration by parts and $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log t}{1+t^2}\,dt = -K$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log(t)\log(1+t^2)\,dt = 4-2K-\tfrac{\pi}{2}-\log 2 $$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log^2(1+t^2)\,dt = 8-4K-2\pi-4\log 2 +2\pi\log 2+\log^2(2).\tag{B}$$
By enforcing the substitution $x=\arctan t$ in the original integral, then exploiting $(A)$ and $(B)$, we may prove the claim in a straightfoward way. Probably $K$ and $\log^2 2$ disappear from the final outcome by a hidden symmetry. This leaves some room for extra slickness.